# mouseover event doesn't get triggered

Tags: javascript

my problem may be simple, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I've got a script, that changes classes of an svg element, when mouseover event occurs.

```js
const navbarExpand = document.getElementById('navbarExpand');
navbarExpand.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
    document.getElementById('navbarIcon').className = "nav__dropdown-icon nav__dropdown-icon--hovered";
});
```

```html
<li class="nav__dropdown-item nav__dropdown-item--expand">
  <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--dropdown">
      <svg class="nav__dropdown-icon" id="navbarIcon">
          <use xlink:href="assets/icons/sprite.svg#double-right-arrow"></use>
      </svg>
      Aktualności
  </a>
  <ul class="nav__dropdown--expand" id="navbarExpand">
    <li class="nav__dropdown-item"><a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--dropdown">Placeholder</a></li>
    <li class="nav__dropdown-item"><a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--dropdown">Placeholder</a></li>
    <li class="nav__dropdown-item"><a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--dropdown">Placeholder</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Console doesn't say anything. I wanna do it in vanilla js, not jQuery.

Comment: Check `onmouseover` .this might work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not className (lieke in react) but classList [class List MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

And not mouseover becease this event is called more time that you need it even can cause blinking (TLTW) but in general check this: [MousEnter vs mouseOver MDM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event)

```
<script>
const navbarExpand = document.getElementById('navbarExpand');

navbarExpand.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  document.getElementById('navbarIcon').classList.add("nav__dropdown-icon--hovered");
});
navbarExpand.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  document.getElementById('navbarIcon').classList.remove("nav__dropdown-icon--hovered");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The className property on an SVG element has a different definition from the className property of an HTML element.

In HTML, className is a string. In SVG it is an SVGAnimatedString object. That's why you can't just do `svgElement.className = "navIconclassname"`.

However, element.setAttribute() will work
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

```
 <li class="nav__dropdown-item nav__dropdown-item--expand">
                        <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--dropdown">
                            <svg class="nav__dropdown-icon" id="navbarIcon">
                                <use xlink:href="assets/icons/sprite.svg#double-right-arrow"></use>
                            </svg>
                            Aktualności
                        </a>
    
                        <ul class="nav__dropdown--expand" id="navbarExpand">
                            <li class="nav__dropdown-item"><a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--dropdown">Placeholder</a></li>
                            <li class="nav__dropdown-item"><a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--dropdown">Placeholder</a></li>
                            <li class="nav__dropdown-item"><a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--dropdown">Placeholder</a></li>
                        </ul>
    
                        <script>
                         
       const navbarExpand = document.getElementById('navbarExpand');
                            navbarExpand.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
       var navBarIcon = document.getElementById('navbarIcon'); navBarIcon.setAttribute("class"," nav__dropdown-icon  nav__dropdown-icon--hovered");
                            });
    
                        </script>
    
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `className` to update the class of the svg. Perhaps try using `setAttribute` or `classList.add`

```
const navbarIcon = document.getElementById('navbarIcon');
navbarIcon.setAttribute('class', 'nav__dropdown-icon nav__dropdown-icon--hovered');
// or
navbarIcon.classList.add('nav__dropdown-icon--hovered');
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try to use `toggle` in your class like this `document.getElementById('navbarIcon').className.toggle("nav__dropdown-icon--hovered");`

Hope this helps <3